# Flutter page dragging functionalities

Tags: flutter, draggable, swipe

Hello flutter developers,
I am trying to develop a project which has dragging functionalities.
[Here is the demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHGcE.png)

Here i have three page. On page A when i swipe from left to right page B will appear from left of the screen but the page transition will be like i'm actually dragging the page. And when i swipe right to left page C will appear.

If someone could provide me any idea like how can i achieve that or any documentation be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try PageView.builder widget. Here is some example code that has three centered text widgets passed as a list to the PageView. You would provide the list of your A, B & C pages.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Hello World',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}


class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
        /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.
        // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: controller,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text('First Page'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Second Page'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Third Page'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For further reference and to read more about its several properties, you may refer to the official documentation here: [Official Flutter PageView Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) or a Medium article here: [A bit advanced usage of PageView](https://betterprogramming.pub/custom-horizontal-scroll-with-pageview-builder-10604dad3b30)

Answer (score 0):

You can use page view to achieve this layout

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```